# NPM global package config file is deleted on update

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating a **global npm package**. (That I use to deploy a software, not a library)

It has a config/ folder with a **config.json.sample** inside.
The user rename it to **config.json** and input his config.

If I do **npm update -g mypackage**, the full folder is overridden :

- The config.json.sample is replaced by the one in the package (good !)
- My problem : The config.json (created by the user, doesn't exist in the package) is **deleted**

I'd like user-created config file to persist after the update.
Is there any way (npm script, flag file as config, anything) that can make user-created files in my package persistent across updates ?

To make cross-platform/permission management easier I really don't want to put this config file outside the package (in /home/user/ for example)

Answer (score 0):

The description of how you are trying deploy your app sound like you are going against the design of npm in general...

What would be the best way is to get your users to create a new project and include your package in it as a dependency, then provide a way inside your module to accept a configuration file from outside...

otherwise what your are talking here sounds like 'hacking' into already published package and modifying its contents, which is not what npm is used for